# Open new activity and change spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

How to change spinner in new activity when button in previous activity was clicked
i have 2 buttons in activity1
if i click first button it should open activity2 with spinner s1
if second is clicked then spinner should be s2

here is the code, i can only open new activity

```
switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.release:
            Intent wg = new Intent("com.pttest.com.pockettankstips.release");
            startActivity(wg);
            break;
        case R.id.alpha:
            Intent cg = new Intent("com.pttest.com.pockettankstips.release");
            startActivity(cg);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write FirstActivity `onCreate`

```
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.pttest.com.pockettankstips.release");
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("index",1);  
            intent.putExtras(b); 
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.pttest.com.pockettankstips.release");
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("index",2);  
            intent.putExtras(b); 
            startActivity(intent);          
        }
    });
```

Write SecondActivity (`com.pttest.com.pockettankstips.release`) `onCreate`

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    int index = b.getInt("index");

    if(index == 1){
        //s1 spinner
        //example: show spinner1
        //spinner1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //spinner2.setVisibility(View.GONE);        
    }else{
        //s2 spinner
        //example: show spinner2
        //spinner1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```